# Wait on callback when minimizing app in android (C# in Unity3d)

Tags: c#, android, callback, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am using [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) to save and load data to google play services cloud (Great plugin btw!). This all works well when I use the exit button in my game, and continue playing after this.

What I want to achieve is saving data on "OnApplicationPause" so that when a player minimizes the game and forgets it (or minimizes, kills, and restarts) he/she does not start back at the last "save point".

The problem is that to save the data the play-games-plugin uses a callback:

```
((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).UpdateState(slot, mySaveState, this);
```

will call:

```
public void OnStateSaved(bool success, int slot);
```

When it is done. But the game has already minimized and stopped processing by the time the UpdateState finishes.

I have tried to use [System.Threading.Autoresetevent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) but this does not work.
I was also looking at normal threading, but found many warnings about Unity not being thread safe so didn't continue on that road.

How can I make the game wait for this finished signal before minimizing (or save the data in the background?)

OnApplicationPause says something about use as a coroutine, this might be an answer but I'm not sure how I would use this.